# sqlalchemy: How to bind a list of parameters to a literal string?

Tags: sqlalchemy

While I use proper ORM-mappers for most of my application, there is a few very complicated to implement. That's why I tried to use [Literal-SQL](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#orm-tutorial-literal-sql).

Now I want to pass a list of values as parameter to that query.

A simplified example of the problem looks as follows:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3]
session.query('name') \
  .from_statement('SELECT name FROM users WHERE id IN(:ids)') \
  .params(ids=ids).all()
```

This doesn't work due to the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.

So how can I make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like sqlalchemy doesn't know what to do with the list type in params, though I suspect the error you listed was from another example based on parameter 2 being the problem.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952546/sqlite3-interfaceerror-error-binding-parameter-1-probably-unsupported-type) is a link that addresses your listed error. For the list issue, you could try something like:

```
def makeSQLList(myList):
    if not myList:
        return "()"
    newString = "(" + str(myList[0])
    for i in range(1,len(myList)):
        newString += "," + str(myList[i])
    newString += ")"
    return newString

ids = [1, 2, 3]
session.query('name') \
  .from_statement(text('SELECT name FROM users WHERE id IN ' + makeSQLList(ids))) \
  .all()
```

Or you could extend sqlalchemy to accept whatever type you're having a problem with. Or, try posting your complicated query and maybe the community can help simplify using the ORM-mappers. Hope one of these options helps!

Comment: Yes, in my original problem the list parameters was the third.