# Not able to insert into sqlite3 using python

Tags: python, sqlite

Insert query is giving unsupported type error

```
def insert_history(self, time, date, url):

    db = sqlite3.connect('/home/amol/BE_project/Browser.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    params = (url, time, date)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO history(url, time, DATE) values(?, ?, ?)",params)
    db.commit()
```

Getting the following error:

> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO history(url, time, DATE) values(?, ?,
>   ?)",params) sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 -
>   probably unsupported type.

The schema is:

```
sqlite> .schema history
CREATE TABLE history(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, url TEXT , time text, DATE text );
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952546/sqlite3-interfaceerror-error-binding-parameter-1-probably-unsupported-type already has been answered

Comment: if it doesnt help,elobrate your issue.what is the type of variables you are passing and suppported in DB as well