# inserting multiple values - sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, database, list, sqlite, sql-insert

Error:

> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO details (user_id, first_name, surname,
> role, make, model, colour, reg) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
> details_default_values) sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding
> parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Code that causes this error to occur:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('collyers_car_park.db')

cursor = connection.cursor()

# create details table
details_table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
details(
user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
first_name TEXT,
surname TEXT,
role TEXT,
make TEXT,
model TEXT,
colour TEXT,
reg TEXT)"""

details_default_values = [
    ('1','Bob','Smith','Staff','Lamborgini','Aventador', 'Red', 'RE05 KDJ'),
    ('2','Sarah','McDonald','Staff','Ferrari','LaFerrari', 'Yellow', 'TY07 PER'),
    ('3','Will','Stevenson','Student','Bugatti','Veyron', 'Green', 'RE62 LKD'),
    ('4','Steve','Swimswam','Student','Renault','Clio', 'Pink', 'RE66 KPO'),
    ('5','Harry','Reeto','Visitor','VW','Up!', 'Blue', 'RZ05 FSD'),
    ('5','Harry','Reeto','Visitor','VW','Up!', 'Blue', 'RZ05 FSD'),
    ('5','Harry','Reeto','Visitor','VW','Up!', 'Blue', 'RZ05 FSD'),
    ('5','Harry','Reeto','Visitor','VW','Up!', 'Blue', 'RZ05 FSD'),
]

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO details (user_id, first_name, surname, role, make, model, colour, reg) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", details_default_values)
```

I thought it was an issue with the `user_id` column being in a string format, but I still get the same error when I get rid of the inverted commas around them.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952546/sqlite3-interfaceerror-error-binding-parameter-1-probably-unsupported-type) post may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert more than 1 rows, so instead of `cursor.execute()` use `cursor.executemany()`:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO ....", details_default_values)
connection.commit()
```

But, there is another problem, because you have duplicate `user_id`s to insert and this will result in a `UNIQUE constraint failed` error.
Make sure that all `user_id`s are unique.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.

The duplicate values were only there to bypass another error which appears to have disappeared now.

Comment: What does `.commit()` do?

Comment: `commit()` saves all the changes you made to the database and makes them visible to other connections to the database. You can read more here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html