# Unable to insert timestamp type in sqlite3 DB

Tags: python, sqlite

I am unable to insert timestamp value in sqlite3 DB, getting 'parameters are of unsupported type' error, below is the code for same

query
Out[21]: 'insert into TOKENxyz values (?)'

vals
Out[22]: Timestamp('2022-03-31 15:21:06')

c.execute(query,vals)
Traceback (most recent call last):

ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Note - for table TOKENxyz only one column is there for supporting timestamp data type

Comment: SQLite doesm't know how to handle a `Timestamp` object; convert it to a string or a datetime before inserting, or consider creating an [adapter/converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69268434/5320906).